# Generic vs Specific MyPy types of functions

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I remember reading, or hearing somewhere that for a function, input types should be as generic as possible (`Iterable` over `list`), but return types should be as specific as possible.

Is this written down somewhere official that I can reference when this comes up in team discussions? Or am I crazy and this isn't actually a guideline?

Comment: It may be hard to find a reference that is specific to mypy/Python, but this is true for any language that has any sort of type system. It all boils down to "don't impose arbitrary / unnecessary restrictions on a function's signature". If a function doesn't rely on its inputs meeting a certain requirement (e.g. "supports random access"), then you shouldn't have it be a requirement. Likewise, if function provides some guarantee about its output (e.g. "has finite length"), you shouldn't hide that information from its users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick google hasn't found anything "official", but the benefits seem self-evident to me, so I'll take a crack at explaining them and you can decide whether the explanation sounds official enough.

### Making parameter types as general as possible

The main benefit of this is in making the calling code simple.  Suppose you have a silly function like this:

```
def add_ints(nums: list[int]) -> int:
    return sum(nums)
```

This works fine, but what if your caller has a `tuple[int, int, int]`?

```
nums = (1, 2, 3)
print(add_ints(nums))        # fails
print(list(add_ints(nums)))  # works
```

This is silly; there's no good reason for them to have to convert their tuple to a list, other than the fact that you decided to annotate your function to require one.  It's extra code to write (and read) and it'll also make it a little slower at runtime.  You should instead define `add_ints` to take an `Iterable[int]`:

```
from typing import Iterable

def add_ints(nums: Iterable[int]) -> int:
    return sum(nums)
```

A second benefit is that it is easier to infer from the type annotation what the function does.  If the function takes a `list`, there is a possibility that it might mutate it, since the `list` interface allows mutation; an `Iterable` isn't mutable, so we can now tell at a glance that even if we pass `add_ints` a `list`, it isn't going to try to modify it -- and `mypy` will enforce that within the implementation of `add_ints` as well!

### Making return types as specific as possible

This is just the corollary to the above.  Suppose you have:

```
def nums_up_to(top: int) -> Iterable[int]:
    return list(range(top))
```

This is technically valid -- but what if our caller needs a list?  Again, we're forcing them to do needless checking/conversion:

```
nums = nums_up_to(5)
nums.append(add_ints(nums))  # fails, can't append to an iterable
```

```
nums = nums_up_to(5)
assert isinstance(nums, list)
nums.append(add_ints(nums))  # works because we narrowed the type with that assert
```

```
nums = list(nums_up_to(5))
nums.append(add_ints(nums))  # works because we explicitly constructed a list
```

Again, this is much more easily fixed by just improving the type annotation:

```
def nums_up_to(top: int) -> list[int]:
    return list(range(top))

nums = nums_up_to(5)
nums.append(add_ints(nums))  # fine!
```

### Remember: YAGNI

It's worth remembering that applying these guidelines is something that doesn't necessarily need to be done rigorously up front -- widening a parameter type and narrowing a return type are both backwards-compatible changes as far as the caller is concerned.

In practice I usually find myself applying these guidelines when I'm in the process of writing calling code, I find that I'm doing some unnecessary type conversion, and I resolve the issue by loosening/tightening the annotation in the dependency rather than working around it in my own code, trusting that mypy will let me know if my annotation doesn't match the actual implementation.